# Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I have observe this issue where I have long character such as 100-4000 characters sending on sendkeys, doesnot work in selenium grid in parallel and breaks in between with the below exception. Does any one have idea about this exception ?

```html
Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <
Build info: version: 'xxxxx', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-xx-xx-3-xx.xx.x', ip: 'xxxxxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 'x-x.x.x', java.version: '1.8.0_312'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'ip-xx-xxx-3-xxx.xxx.internal', ip: 'xxxxxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'xx', os.version: 'xx-xx.xx.xxx', java.version: '1.8.0_312'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

```
public String generateString(int length) {
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random rand = null;
    try {
        rand = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        char c = chars[rand.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    String first = sb.toString();
    log.info(first);
    return first;
}
```

Calling this above method with the following-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath="xxxxxxx").sendKeys(generateString(4067));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do it using javascript Executor

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor ) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+generateString(4067)+"'", element);
```

Comment: that doesnot work